# Contains inside Linq-to-Entities

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need to implement search by term and store in `IQueryable` but Entity Framework doesn't allow to use `Contains` method in Linq-to-Entities, how can I replace it?

```
query = query.Where(e => e.Fullname.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
                         e.Email.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
                         e.Username.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: Note that you cannot control if the comparison will be case sensitive or not as that will be determined by the collation in the DB once the code is converted to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework Core has a built in function `EF.Functions` in the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace.
You could use it as such

```
query = query.Where(e => EF.Functions.FreeText(e.Fullname, searchTerm) || EF.Functions.Contains(e.Email, searchTerm)); //etc
```

Note. To use this function `FullTextSearch` index should be configured on the table columns.
I personally use `Postgres` and this is the [documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/full-text-search.html?tabs=pg12%2Cv5) on how to configure `FullTextSearch` index on an entity. Find out how to configure such indexes from you provider.

Answer (score 0):

remove `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`

```
query = query.Where(e => e.Fullname.Contains(searchTerm) || 
                         e.Email.Contains(searchTerm) ||
                         e.Username.Contains(searchTerm));
```

Linq to SQL translates `Contains("searchterm")` into `like '%searchterm%'` which is case insensitive

Comment: Actually it's only case incensitive based on the collation of the DB which typically defaults to case insensitive.